# document function in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am triggering the transformation using a .NET4 code.

the transformation works just fine, when I write the xpath with the document function directly in the xslt (see element PanelOK in the example xslt):

but when the xPath itself is stored in a variable, it won't work (see element PanelException):

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Customer"/>
```

where @Customer has the value "document('myXml.xml')/COM:root/COM:Global/@Customer"

Then I extended my xslt with a script. This works fine when I'm not using the document function in the xpath, e.g. only /COM:root/COM:Global/@Customer. But with the document function I get the exception **XsltContext is needed for this query because of an unknown function.**

Here are the examples: xml1 has the attribute customer with the value containing the xpath expression, xml2 is the file where the value can be found, xslt is the transformation which transforms xml1 and evaluates the xpath expression stored in the attribute customer which should look up the value in the xml2 using the custom script where the excpetion then in the select statement occurs. What must I do to get this working?

xml1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<SFK:root xmlns:SFK="http://www.Test.com/SoftKeys">
  <SFK:Panel Customer="document('setting.xml')/COM:root/COM:Global/@Customer">
  </SFK:Panel>
</SFK:root>
```

xml2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<COM:root xmlns:COM="http://www.Test.com/Comm">
  <COM:Global Customer="Microsoft">
  </COM:Global>
</COM:root>
```

xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
                xmlns:SFK="http://www.Test.com/SoftKeys"
                xmlns:COM="http://www.Test.com/Comm"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                extension-element-prefixes="dyn msxsl"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl xsl SFK COM dyn">

    <!--Script to evaluate a string xPath to a Node. the real evaluate extension is not implemented in MS xslt processor-->
    <msxsl:script implements-prefix="dyn" language="C#">
        <![CDATA[
            public XPathNodeIterator evaluate(XPathNavigator context, string expression)
            {
                XmlNamespaceManager mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
                mngr.AddNamespace("SFK","http://www.Test.com/SoftKeys");
                mngr.AddNamespace("COM","http://www.Test.com/Comm");
                mngr.AddNamespace("msxsl","urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt");

                return context.Select(expression,mngr); // here occurs the exception
            }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="current()/SFK:root/SFK:Panel"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SFK:Panel">
        </PanelOk>
            <xsl:value-of select="document('xml2.xml')/COM:root/COM:Global/@Customer"/>
         </PanelOk>
         </PanelException>
            <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(., @Customer)"/>
         </PanelException>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation why this is not possible without extensions, and not possible at all with the .NET xslt processors of today. Workarounds are possible, and if you indicate that you are interested in such -- probably ask a new question and define it to be as specific as possible -- I will be glad to provide such workarounds.

Comment: First, inline extensions functions definitions is not the standard XSLT content model. Second, you are trying to use and XSLT function with an XPath engine. Besides the classic solution of two step transformations (a stylesheet transforms input source into a new stylesheet wich output the final result) and simple traversing templates, I would also recommend to split the information in two: path and document as in `<SFK:Panel Customer="/COM:root/COM:Global/@Customer" Source="setting.xml"/>`.

Comment: Also do note that there were efforts to provide XSLT context to XPath evaluation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950808.aspx

Comment: @Dimitre: I'm very interested in a workaround. I posted a new question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922578/workaround-for-dynamic-evaluation-of-document-function-in-xslt

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the `document` function is not defined in the XPath specification and therefore not available in an XPath 1.0 implementation like Microsoft's XPathNavigator. The `document` function is defined in XSLT only.

I am not sure what to suggest, with Saxon 9 or with XQSharp you could use the XPath 2.0 `doc` function instead but I am not sure you want to move from the .NET framework's built-in XSLT and XPath 1.0 implementation to a third party XSLT and XPath 2.0 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

**The EXSLT function `dyn:evaluate` is not implemented in the microsoft XSLT processors**.

You may workaround this if different parts of the desired XPath expression are coded in separate elements/attributes of xml1.

Of course, this is a very limited solution that requires conventions and discipline.

**Dynamic evaluation of XPath expressions is not supported even in XSLT 2.0/XPath2.0** . Such support may be available in later versions, but the 3.0 versions still have "working draft" status.